# Python-Creating a Class- x object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, class, parsing, split

I am trying to create a class which takes a URL and allows me to split it into parts and return each of the scheme, server, and path.

```
class SimpleURL:
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url=url
    def scheme(self):
        return url.split("://")[0]
    def server(self):
        return url.split("/")[2]
    def path(self):
        return url.split(url.split("/")[2])[1]

test_url = SimpleURL("https://gumgoose.com/larry/friendo")
```

Then, if I run

```
test_url.scheme()
```

or any server or path, I get the error

```
   NameError: name 'url' is not defined
```

I am able to make it work if I assign the url to the variable "url" outside of the function, but to my understanding, the line beginning "test_url" should be doing that for me.

Can anybody shed some light onto this for me?

Comment: Are you doing this just for practice? If you really want to parse URL's, this is a module in the standard lib: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Answer (score 3):

Within all of your class methods, you will need to explicitly use `self` to refer to all other class methods and attributes.

```
def scheme(self):
    return self.url.split('://')[0]
```

If you do not do this, Python will *only* search the local scope within your method *and* the global scope. That is why if you define `url` outside of your class, you don't have any issues.

Comment: Duh! That seems so obvious now, after you've said it. It works perfectly now, thank you!

Comment: @NathanWall If that solved your problem, consider selecting it as a solution to help others with similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Python requires you reference the instance object too i.e.
    return self.url.split('://')[0]