# Python: variables inside class methods

Tags: python, function, class, first-class-functions

I'm learning python and am trying to write a wound system based on hot zones of a character. Here's what I've written. Don't judge me too much.

```
class Character:
    def __init__ (self, agility, strength, coordination):
            self.max_agility = 100
            self.max_strength = 100
            self.max_coordination = 100
            self.agility = agility
            self.strength = strength
            self.coordination = coordination

    def hit (self, hit_region, wound):
            self.hit_region = hit_region
            self.wound = wound

            #Hit Zones
            l_arm=[]
            r_arm=[]
            l_leg=[]
            r_leg=[]
            hit_region_list = [l_arm , r_arm, l_leg, r_leg]


            #Wound Pretty Names
            healthy = "Healthy"
            skin_cut = "Skin Cut"
            muscle_cut = "Muscle Cut"
            bone_cut = "Exposed Bone"

            hit_region.append(wound)              

john = Character(34, 33, 33)

john.hit(l_arm, skin_cut)
```

I'd expect for the skin_cut input to be recognized as "Skin Cut", then added to l_arm, which I defined as a list. However, I always get a name error (l_arm is not defined). If i rewrite the method with the 'wound' as the first argument,the Name Error now comes with 'wound' as not defined. That kind of tells me it's something in the structure of the class I've missed, but I can't tell what.

Comment: Local variables, e.g. l_arm, are destroyed when a function finishes executing.

Comment: Can you please provide error?

Comment: @Lafada, It's obvious!

Comment: `l_arm`, `skin_cut` only exist within the scope of your `hit` method.

Comment: @Lafada The error has been provided already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python-Creating a Class- x object has no attribute 'split'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103486/python-creating-a-class-x-object-has-no-attribute-split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my previous answer to this.

```
class Character:
def __init__ (self, agility, strength, coordination):
        self.max_agility = 100
        self.max_strength = 100
        self.max_coordination = 100
        self.agility = agility
        self.strength = strength
        self.coordination = coordination
        self.l_arm=[]
        self.r_arm=[]
        self.l_leg=[]
        self.r_leg=[]
        self.hit_region_list = [self.l_arm , self.r_arm, self.l_leg, self.r_leg]
        self.healthy = "Healthy"
        self.skin_cut = "Skin Cut"
        self.muscle_cut = "Muscle Cut"
        self.bone_cut = "Exposed Bone"

def hit (self, hit_region, wound):
        self.hit_region = hit_region
        self.wound = wound
        hit_region.append(wound)
        #Hit Zones



        #Wound Pretty Names




john = Character(34, 33, 33)

john.hit(john.l_arm,john.skin_cut)

print john.hit_region
print john.l_arm
```

After running the above code I got this output

```
output:
['Skin Cut']
['Skin Cut']
```

As per the post, I think this is what you wanted. According to your previous code, your declarations were accessible inside a function only. Now You can manipulate the data and these variables for particular instances by declaring them inside the constructor.

Comment: There is much more to it than just that. Look at the code again.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My bad. I updated my answer.

Comment: np. You should fix your indentation and provide a bit of an explanation as to why you are providing that code change. The more context around why the code you are providing fixes their problem, the better. Just some friendly advice. :)

Comment: That solves my comprehension problem, at least. Thanks a lot. I was avoiding this solution because using a list or iterable of hitzones seemed like a dryer answer, but if this works it' nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You define `l_arm` in function and its local to that function only. It has scope of function only. That can be accessed inside function only.

You try to access `l_arm` outside function, and that gives error, `l_arm` is not defined.

If you want to access all these variable outside function, you can define it above `class`

```
#Hit Zones
l_arm=[]
r_arm=[]
l_leg=[]
r_leg=[]
hit_region_list = [l_arm , r_arm, l_leg, r_leg]


#Wound Pretty Names
healthy = "Healthy"
skin_cut = "Skin Cut"
muscle_cut = "Muscle Cut"
bone_cut = "Exposed Bone"

class Character:
    ...
    ...
    ...

john = Character(34, 33, 33)

john.hit(l_arm, skin_cut)
```

This will work.

Comment: This gives me some information, but if I define the hit region empty lists outside (before) the class it'll be impossible to have different hit lists for different characters. Maybe if I define the variables in the class __init__?.

Answer (score 0):

Every local variable assigned within a function is thrown away as soon as the function ends. You need to prepend `self.` to those names so that they are saved as instance variables, such as `self.l_arm`, `self.r_arm`, and so on. The same goes for the wound pretty names, if you plan on using those objects later on.

Comment: Wasn't me....However, there is a bit more to solving OP problem than that I think. They are trying to call the `hit` method by assigning variables that are created inside `hit`. So, those attributes actually need to be available before even calling that method. Probably in their init as well..